# Sum of all odd fibonacci numbers upto n

Tags: javascript

I am stuck in summing up to number 10. Can't get it right.
What i am getting is the total sum from 10 digits (after filtering odd only 7). Where should i make <= num ?

```js
function sumFibs(num) {
  var fib = [1, 1];
  for (var i = 2; i < num; i++) {
    var next = fib[i - 1] + fib[i - 2];
    var fibi = fib.push(next);
  }

  return fib.filter(function(a) {
      return (a % 2 != 0);
    })
    .reduce(function(a, z) {
      return a + z;
    })
}
console.log(sumFibs(10));
```

Expected output 10, but getting 99

Comment: Why expected output is `10`?

Comment: 10 is not a Fibonacci number, correct me if I'm wrong... or is that 10 items of Fibonacci row?

Comment: because these are odd numbers 1,1,3,5 up to sum of 10

Comment: `1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55`, if you sum up all odd numbers it gives `1 + 1 + 3 + 5 +13 + 21 + 55` = 99. Your code works as intended, I guess

Comment: if you want to get the sum of the first 10 Fibonacci numbers, taking into account only odd numbers… 99 is the expected output

Comment: @U25lYWt5IEJhc3RhcmQg `10` is supposed to be the *sum* of the fibonacci numbers...but you cannot get `10` - the sum of `1`, `1`, `2`, `3` is `7` and if you add `5` you get to `12`

Comment: if you'll put in console before filter you'll see them Fibonacci

Comment: You go through the first 10 Fibonacci numbers and sum the odd ones. Those are: 1, 1, [2], 3, 5, [8], 13, 21, [34], 55 (those in [square brackets] are even and don't count). Together, that's 99.

Comment: i have to sum all odd fib numbers to the sum(num) which is <10 in this case

Comment: Do you want to get odd fibonacci numbers < 10 and sum them up?

Comment: @VLAZ 2 is not an odd number, so wouldn't be part of the sum.

Comment: yes all numbers that are <10.

Comment: the code is correct up to   sumFibs(4)

Comment: because all odd Fib numbers that are <10 are 1,1,3,5

Answer (score 3):

Add `a < num` to your filter callback test, so you get `a % 2 && a < num`

```js
function sumFibs(num) {
 var fib = [0, 1];
 for (var i = 2; i < num; i++) {
  var next = fib[i - 1] + fib[i - 2];
  var fibi = fib.push(next);
 }
 return fib.filter(function (a) {
  return a % 2 && a < num;
 }).reduce(function (a, z) {
  return a + z;
 }, 0);
}

console.log(sumFibs(0))
console.log(sumFibs(1))
console.log(sumFibs(10))
console.log(sumFibs(9000))
```

You don't need to use array at all if you need only sum of those numbers

```js
function sumFibs(num) {
  if(num <= 1) return 0;
  var a = 0, b = 1, sum = a + b;
  while(true) {
    var next = a + b;
    if(next >= num) {
      break;
    }
    if(next % 2) {
      sum += next;
    }
    a = b;
    b = next;
  }
  return sum
}
console.log(sumFibs(0))
console.log(sumFibs(1))
console.log(sumFibs(10))
console.log(sumFibs(9000))
```

Comment: Note that the whole return statement can be condensed into `return fib.filter(a => a%2 && a < num).reduce((a, z)  => a + z)`.

Comment: @ponury-kostek Thank you !!! You saved me. It took me all day yesterday ... I just added a<=num to the filter and it passed the code !

Comment: I would delete your first solution as misleading one. Your second method with that small workaround works perfectly and much faster than my answer, so you got my upvote too.

Comment: @U25lYWt5IEJhc3RhcmQg both fixed

Comment: Your first method still needs to create array of 9000 elements and filter/reduce that to get `console.log(sumFibs(9000))`

Comment: You would need to do `for (var i = 2; fib[i-1] < num; i++)` to get it fixed. It will make `&& a < num` part of your filter condition unnecessary.

Comment: @U25lYWt5IEJhc3RhcmQg first method is for OP, and returns same results as second one. For what input you have different results?

Comment: It doesn't make sense to suggest only that small fix deliberately ignoring that huge performance breach that can make that app run 100 times slower whie can be fixed with equally small correction. As being said, if your answer gets eventually accepted, that would be misleading.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the loop condition. Loop till the last value of `fib` is less than `num`

```js
function sumFibs(num) {
  var fib = [1, 1];
  for (var i = 2; fib[fib.length - 1] < num; i++) {
    var next = fib[i - 1] + fib[i - 2];
    fib.push(next);
  }
   return fib
    .filter(x => !(x % 2))
    .reduce((ac,a) => ac + a,0)
}
console.log(sumFibs(10));
```

Comment: I'm getting 3380 ? Is something wrong here or it just me?

Comment: @Rahul Where have you need this question. Please elaborate clearly. The result `10` doesn't make any sense. How the result is `10` can you tell?

Comment: The sum of the first 10 odd numbers would be 798, not 3380.

Comment: @MaheerAli I think the OP meant to sum those fibonacci numbers which are less than 10 `1 + 1 + 3 + 5`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to retain your code for the most part, you can add an `if` statement that breaks the loop once your `next` number goes beyond your `num`:

```js
function sumFibs(num) {
  var fib = [1, 1];
  for (var i = 2; i < num; i++) {
    var next = fib[i - 1] + fib[i - 2];

    if ( next > num ) { // not >= assuming you want to include your num
      break;
    }

    fib.push(next);
  }
  console.log({fib});
  
  return fib.filter(function(a) {
      return (a % 2 != 0);
    })
    .reduce(function(a, z) {
      return a + z;
    })
}
console.log(sumFibs(10));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is summing the first N Fibonacci numbers that are odd. You seem to be looking for the first odd Fibonacci numbers that sum to N:

```js
function oddFibsThatAddTo(target)
{
  let currentFib = 1;
  let lastFib = 1;
  let sum = 2;
  const outs = [1,1];
  while(sum < target)
  {
    let nextFib = currentFib + lastFib;
    if(nextFib % 2 == 1)
    {
      sum += nextFib;
      outs.push(nextFib);
    }
    lastFib = currentFib;
    currentFib = nextFib;
  }
  if(sum > target)
  {
    throw 'can\'t find perfect sequence';
  }
  return outs;
}

console.log(oddFibsThatAddTo(10))
```

Answer (score -1):

```
function sumFibs(num) {
  var fib=[1,1];
  for(var i=2; i<num; i++){
  var next=fib[i-1]+fib[i-2];
  var fibi=fib.push(next);
}
return fib.filter(function(a){
  return(a%2!=0 && a<=num);
})
.reduce(function(a,z){
 return a+z;
})
}
console.log(sumFibs(10));
```

Comment: Thanks to everybody ! @ ponury-kostek pointed to add a<num in the filter and it worked perfectly without changing anything. Have a nice day !

Comment: please always add some explanation to the answers... you answer could be better and more useful for future users